# How do I delete a custom room?

Tags: rec-room

I have a lot of rooms in my list that I want to get rid of but I can't find anywhere in the game that allows me to delete them. Where is the delete button for rooms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no delete button in game, you have to delete the room on rec.net:

1. Log in with your Rec Room account on https://rec.net/
2. Click on your profile image
3. Click on the house symbol to get to your rooms
4. Click on the room that you want to delete
5. Click on the gear symbol for the settings of the room
6. Click the "Delete" tab
7. Click the "Delete" button
8. Follow the instructions (i.e. type in the name of your room and confirm)